# python module moviepy CompositeVideoClip Combining problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, video, moviepy

```
from moviepy.editor import *  

picture = VideoFileClip("img.jpg", audio=False).set_duration(50)

textOne = "First Line!"
textTwo = "Second Caption!!!!"
textThree = "Third one!!!"

texts = [textOne, textTwo, textThree]

step = 15 #each 15 sec: 0, 15, 30
duration = 10
t = 0
txt_clips = []
for text,i in zip(texts,range(0,3)):
  txt_clip = TextClip(text,fontsize = 40, color='white')
  txt_clip = txt_clip.set_start(t)
  txt_clip = txt_clip.set_pos('center').set_duration(duration)
  txt_clips.append(txt_clip)  
  t += step
  
audio = AudioFileClip(r"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\Kalimba.mp3").subclip(0,50)

video_with_new_audio = picture.set_audio(audio)

final_video = CompositeVideoClip([video_with_new_audio,txt_clips[0],txt_clips[1],txt_clips[2]])

final_video.write_videofile("TEXT.mp4")
```

Here in the last line of:

```
final_video = CompositeVideoClip([video_with_new_audio,txt_clips[0],txt_clips[1],txt_clips[2]])
```

I do not want to write like `txt_clips[0],txt_clips[1]` as my input for txt_clips is taken from user which can be more than 3

how to do it?
and
**[video_with_new_audio] + txt_clips**
above doesn't work